# How to override a function parameter type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I am working on a class based project and I have my main class that I usually extend to other files since the implementation is pretty similar.

This is one of my functions in the `BaseSummaryManager` Page Object file:

```
protected handleGetSummary(summary: SummaryResponse) {
    return {
        account_number: summary.AccountNumber,
        first_name: summary.FirstName,
        last_name: summary.LastName,
        email: summary.Email.trim().toLowerCase(),
    };
}
```

And the problem that I'm having is that in one specific servicer that extends `BaseSummaryManager`, I need to return a different object, like this:

```
return {
    account_number: summary.Data.AccountNumber,
    first_name: summary.Data.FirstName,
    last_name: summary.Data.LastName,
    email: summary.Data.Email.trim().toLowerCase(),
};
```

Do you guys see the .Data that was not present in the main implementation?
So to handle this case I created a override function like this:

```
protected override handleGetSummary(summary: CustomSummaryResponse) {
    return {
        account_number: summary.Data.AccountNumber,
        first_name: summary.Data.FirstName,
        last_name: summary.Data.LastName,
        email: summary.Data.Email.trim().toLowerCase(),
    };
}
```

Using `CustomSummaryResponse` that has the `Data` object.

The problem I'm facing is that Typescript won't allow me to change the parameter type in my servicer implementation.
I get this message:

```
 Property 'handleGetSummary' in type 'CustomSummaryResponse' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BaseSummaryManager'.
  Type '(summary: CustomSummaryResponse) => { account_number: string; first_name: string; last_name: string; email: string; }' is not assignable to type '(summary: SummaryResponse) => { account_number: string; first_name: string; last_name: string; email: string; }'.
    Types of parameters 'summary' and 'summary' are incompatible.
      Type 'CustomSummaryResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'SummaryResponse': AccountNumber, FullName, FirstName, LastName, and 11 more.
```

So what I'm doing wrong here guys? How to override this parameter?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, because a subclass instance must be a valid base class instance, and your instance wouldn't be because the semantics of its `handleGetSummary` method would be different from the base class version. It would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Instead, write a small utility function that turns a `CustomSummaryResponse` into a `SummaryResponse`, and use that when calling `handleGetSummary`.

Comment: thats a very good idea, i will try it and get back here in a few minutes. Thank you!